# Place arrow image directly after sentence in paragraph

Tags: html, css

I have an arrow image that needs to immediately follow the period of the last sentence in each paragraph. This image is surrounded by an href that needs to link to another page. I cannot figure out how to get this arrow to automatically be positioned next to period of sentence (vs left or right aligned all the way to the edge.) Using background image doesn't really work for me because of the href around image. I know there are ways to link a div, but I'd prefer not to handle it that way if possible.

Here is live code: http://codepen.io/trevoray/pen/LVxYrv

### HTML:

```
<div class="column-4-layout">
    <div class="left-column">
        <div class="column-container"> <a href="/renderContent/about/vp/vision.asp"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/financialPolicy-spl.jpg" /></a> 
             <h2>Vision and Policies</h2> 
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In scelerisque ac nunc eu placerat. Sed vulputate iaculis est vitae gravida. Praesent accumsan leo dapibus aliquam interdum. Vestibulum quis nisl volutpat, tempus metus id, scelerisque erat. Suspendisse sed vestibulum magna. Maecenas dignissim, neque ac accumsan molestie, eros felis sagittis sem, sed tempus nunc turpis sed ex. Praesent elit diam, bibendum sed aliquam vel, sollicitudin at turpis. Phasellus sagittis maximus vehicula. Donec vulputate fermentum ligula nec efficitur. Ut magna libero, pulvinar porttitor rutrum et, bibendum vitae libero. Phasellus ac elementum diam. Praesent scelerisque dui id nunc congue semper. <a href="/renderContent/about/vp/vision.asp"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/more-arrow.gif" width="15" /></a>
            </P>
        </div>
        <div class="column-container"> <a href="/renderContent/about/vp/vision.asp"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/financialPolicy-spl.jpg" /></a> 
             <h2>Best Practices</h2> 
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In scelerisque ac nunc eu placerat. Sed vulputate iaculis est vitae gravida. Praesent accumsan leo dapibus aliquam interdum. Vestibulum quis nisl volutpat, tempus metus id, scelerisque erat. Suspendisse sed vestibulum magna. <a href="/renderContent/about/vp/vision.asp"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/more-arrow.gif" width="15" /></a>
            </P>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.column-4-layout {
    color:#565657;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-right:25px;
}
.column-4-layout .column-container {
    width:475px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    min-height:240px;
}
.tall-column-4 .column-container {
    margin-top:40px;
    min-height:0;
    !important;
}
.column-4-layout .column-container img {
    width:227px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    float:left;
}
.column-4-layout .column-container p img {
    width:auto;
    float:right;
    padding-top:5px;
    margin-right:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.column-4-layout .left-column {
    float:left;
}
.column-4-layout .left-column .column-container:first-child {
    margin-top:0px;
}
.column-4-layout .right-column {
    float:right;
}
.column-4-layout .right-column .column-container:first-child {
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find `.column-4-layout .column-container p img` and do following changes into your css file

```
.column-4-layout .column-container p img {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: auto;
}
```

updated your codepen :http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wagvRg

Answer (score 4):

Give the anchor `display: inline-block`.

```
a{
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and remove unnecessary padding from the `img` tag which is inside `anchor` tag of `p` tag.

The exact css to use is:

```
.column-4-layout .column-container p a img {
    padding: 0;
}

 .column-4-layout .column-container p a{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://codepen.io/Mr_Green/pen/zGNYXy)**